# Keyboard version of Ctrl+Click on Windows Taskbar icon

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

(`Ctrl+click`) If you hold control and click on an icon on the Windows taskbar, it will cycle through the windows for only that app.

(`Alt+Esc`) If you hold Alt and tap Esc, it will cycle through all open windows.

What I am looking for is a keyboard-only shortcut to accomplish the former.

(`Win+Tab` and `Alt+Esc`) Currently, my solution is to use a second desktop for just that app and then use `Alt+Esc` to cycle through windows on that desktop.  Unfortunately with the frequency I need to switch between other apps, this is wasting a ton of time for me.

If there is no better option, I might rig something up with AutoHotkey, but I am trying to avoid that type of solution.

Any other options out there that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this app to do that: https://neosmart.net/EasySwitch/

There is a free non-commercial license.

Comment: This is the closest I have found yet, but It seems like this is offers more of a toggle option.  I need to switch, do some work and then switch to the next, etc.  This does somewhat allow cycling through the app while still holding Alt down, but as soon as you relese it (to do the work I need) then it only toggles back.

Comment: For me Alt + `(tilde) will switch window (e.g. browser #1) to a different window (e.g., browser window #2) and releasing Alt leaves me on that different window (browser #2). What app is toggling back when you release Alt?

I tested with the multiple windows open on the browser and again with multiple windows open on Windows File Explorer.

Comment: #1 is open I press Alt+` then #2 is open.  I work a bit and press Alt+` and now #1 is open (toggle) what I need, is the second time I press Alt+` for #3 to open (cycle)

I AM able to cycle with Alt+` as long as I don't release the alt key and keep pressing `, but that doesn't work in the scenario I outlined above.

Comment: Ah yes that is the standard behavior, it always goes back to the most recent window. You can instead go to the least recent window by using Shift key (Alt+Shift+\`): #1 is open, work a bit Alt+Shift+\` to get #3. Work and bit press Alt+Shift+\` to get #2. If you have more windows it will go to the last one (eg #10) and keep working back until you arrive back where you started (#1).

Comment: I haven't tested it, but that would probably work well for me.  If you write it in the answer, I will accept it.  (Leave me a note though, so I get a reminder)

Answer (score -1):

You can move the app icon e.g. to the first position in the taskbar, then just use Ctrl+Win+1, which will be exactly the same as Ctrl+Click.